# How do I perform Riak Solr search using the Java API

Tags: riak

can I perform searches using Solr on Riak with the Java client

I will need to insert the data in Java to support Solr search and then query it

Answer (score 0):

Version 2.0 of Riak, which is currently under development ([there is a technical preview available here](http://docs.basho.com/riak/2.0.0pre5/downloads/)), will contain enhanced full text search capability through deep integration between Solr and Riak. I am not sure if there is a version of the Java client currently available that supports this functionality, but as the release date for 2.0 gets closer it is likely to soon be available.